# Can I print my picture on {A,B,C}{0-10} paper?

Tags: code-golf

The task is to find the smallest paper size on which it is possible to print a picture of the dimensions given in milimetres. The image will be printed without margins.

## Input:

Two integers (bigger than zero) and a letter a, b, or c, for example:

```
290
200
A
```

## Output:

Paper size, for example:

> A4

Another examples:

```
218,297,a      A3
1,1,c          C10
9999,9999,c    ??? (error)
74,52,A        A8
31,44,B        B10
26,1100,A       A0
250,177,b     b4
250,176,b    b5
1189,841,a    a0
```

The dimensions of the paper for \$i \in \{0,\dots, 10\} \$ are:

$$ \left( \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}^{i+1}} , \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}^{i}} \right) $$

where \$\alpha\$ depends on the type of paper:

$$ 
\begin{eqnarray} 
\alpha_A &=& 2 ^ {1/4} \\
\alpha_B &=& 2 ^ {1/2} \\
\alpha_C &=& 2 ^ {3/8} \\
\end{eqnarray} 
$$

---

- Upper- and lowercase variants of letters "A", "B" and "C" are
  allowed on input and on output. You need to handle both of them.
- The image can be printed vertically or horizontally.
- The values can be passed as a parameter or entered by the user.
- Width and height of picture will be always > 0 (and they will be always integers), and letters will be always 'a', 'b', or 'c'. You don't need to validate them.
- You need to handle paper sizes A0 - A10, B0 - B10 and C0 - C10. If the image is too large, you can throw an exception, print an error or whatever you want, as long as it is clearly different from valid result and the application will not hung up.

Paper sizes, please ignore inch values ([source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size#Overview_of_ISO_paper_sizes)) :
[image: Paper sizes]

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) - fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Having to handle both upper and lowercase along with errors isn't normal for these types of challenges. It's usually no errors with simple (and flexible) input to do something computationally intense like this. Or simply indicate if the input is valid or not.

Comment: Does outputting, say, `C-1`  for an image that's too large suffice for printing an invalid result?

Comment: Can you please post the lists as text rather than as an image?

Comment: Sorry for not saying all this where your challenge was in the Sandbox. I hadn't noticed stuff until I started golfing.

Comment: The formula gives floating point numbers, and the dimensions on the wiki page are not `ceil`ed, `floor`ed, or `round`ed, so it's unclear exactly what the intended behavior relative to the formula is. Should we follow the table exactly, or is some error margin tolerable, like 1mm for example? (I would advise the latter, since the value of 841 (which should be 840 if floored, and is the only exception to the rule) is breaking a lot of otherwise clever approaches)

Comment: I'd like to point out that the ISO standard for paper sizes also specifies tolerances of up to 3mm for dimensions above 600mm. This supports @HyperNeutrino's motion to allow for error margins.

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
η⊞θ×⌊θ₂²Ｉ⊖Ｌ↨⌊Ｘ∕×φＸ²∕⁺²⌕ACB↥η⁸⁻⌈θ·²¦²¦²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU5NC4IwGL73K4anV1hhYlB0sqRTgfRxkg5DX9pAN91m9e@X0@rywPs@nyVnulSsdi7XQlrg4XaW94ZDR8lVNGjgJKRo@ga6kJJL1zONZ6UsxGHopaNpz4yFDEuNDUqLFRxRPiyHHTMIh1opDbl6oYZMPEWFMAUvoyiiZCJiSr5cXvfGnwchKwjS/S6g5Na2qEsfxodWStYjDsMG6Ym9//MWsf//wA90rihWm2SwJMs7JUEa3N38WX8A) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a pair of integers and a characters. Explanation:

```
η
```

Output the paper letter.

```
⊞θ×⌊θ₂²
```

Multiply the smaller dimension by √2 and use that if it is larger than the larger dimension.

```
Ｉ⊖Ｌ↨⌊Ｘ∕×φＸ²∕⁺²⌕ACB↥η⁸⁻⌈θ·²¦²¦²
```

Calculate the largest size of paper, divide by the larger dimension (less 0.2 due to rounding errors), square the result, convert to binary, and count the digits (because Charcoal has no logarithm function).

Comment: This doesn't work on `594, 841` with `A` because unfortunately for whatever reason `floor` on the result in the formula on the Wiki page succeeds on everything _except_ the height for page size A1 / width for page size A0.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I now subtract ½ from the value; this seems to fix 841 and 1297 without breaking 1414.

Comment: @AZTECCO OK, I've switched from 0.5 to 0.2, and I think the previous edge cases still work with this value.

Comment: @Neil just like I did, unfortunately it was not clear how rounding works here, I had to test every format to be sure and I found +0.2

Comment: @AZTECCO Yeah, I thought I'd tested all of the formats, so I'm not sure how that one slipped through the net...

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 99 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,c,i=10:max(a)<=1e3*2**(2**ord(c)%5/8-i/2)>=min(a)*2**.5and c+str(max(-1,i))or f(a,c,i-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc3RjoIwEAXQ9/2KJsbYwUE7hQpuRCL7JRUkNhEwyIP79Thodssk05d7euf@O1y7NhrHOrvZ5lxZYbFEl5H6buxTWjhkdIkCHQSSt@srWcLSbNPQbTUcs8a1bKZ4Y2xbiXL9GHo5/QwJHUDXi1q@G0OC8d67dpC1lJpS1PsEcGVXAGKahThFX/@AkDgs/8IP@CHlxZ4Hp8e7hcjz3IskRqM5PfkWPpJ6EBHGMYNiDor5Eb1DIqXmJVwxB0YhJTsGZw8KM74A)

-2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

-12 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).

Comment: -4 bytes with `2**ord(c)%5/8-i/2`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzRDoIwDEXf/YolxmzDoutggEYk4pcMkLhEwCAP@vU4VJCbtElzbs/91V2b2uv7Mr7pKis00ZBBDiZGsa/0k9mTH2K8eI50HGanaQuW85XaRq7ZSn6MK1N/WkNho3RdkHz96Fo2fLsIhvOmJSX7eV3k/b01dcdKJjECuQuBaso5GbIkJ28xYgQEmo/oi88oJr6zgc8aW0uSJMnEQx@UBHr6G6w@mrCH4PtA0zlOZ3oZAKIQM4F9n2ElAMMAaPbHqerf "Python 3 – Try It Online"). And, borrowing from xnor's deleted answer, You can take the dimensions as a tuple and remove every `,b`.

Comment: @ovs Great find, thanks! Although I don't quite follow how `2**ord(c)%5/8` can substitute `-ord(c)%4%3/8+1/4`. Is this just a random coincidence?

Comment: That’s probably a random coincidence, at least I don’t see the reason ;). I just run the values through a bruteforcing script. `7**ord(c)%5/8` happens to work as well.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 157 bytes

```python
lambda x,y,a:a+str((k:=[*zip(A:=[(int(2**((2+-(~-ord(a)%32)%3)/8)/2**(i/2)*1e3+.2))for i in range(12)],A[1:])])and~-sum(y<=q>r>=x or x<=q>r>=y for q,r in k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BboNADEX3PcVsqrHBlIyhDUElErlGymISQjtKM5AJlaCLXJ1C2krEkq3v5//lpm8/ahsljRuq7G341KddqUVHPelU@5fWARzTbOt9mwbyUYCxLbDnAbAfwDWoXQkaHyMeG8MEw@lmQkZPHSL/iRGr2gkjjBVO2/cDKMaC8q1KCyxQ2/IaXL5O0L9m57VbZ50Y3d3f0ospeyY3pY@IQ@Om7xWwSohXS5JaIj78U0WK5H5OVmPRbdzzZUzPTDKfs0hRHJPczBm/kFKLxa9z@AE)

Outputs `X-1` if the image is too large.

-4 bytes thanks to ErikF

Comment: @ErikF oh, thought I was. thanks!

Comment: @ErikF Ah, good catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>189</s> <s>174</s> <s>161</s> 152 bytes

Thanks to ceilingcat for the -37.

The function normalizes the dimensions and then iterates through the sizes until one fits. To return the paper size, `asprintf()` works and makes it so I don't have to have a static array to store the string.

```c
f(w,h,z,x){float q;z=~-z&3,w>h?x=w:(x=h,h=w);for(w=11;round(q=exp2(~z/4./~(z/2)-.5*--w)*1e3)<x|round(q/sqrt(2))<h&&~w;);asprintf(&h,"%c%d",z+65,w);w=h;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVBRboMwDP3PKSImUNKZ0gBt16Vh6s6xnyhAg0ShBbogunL0sdDVsi3bek9@tvKPSk1TTgxoGKCnt7ysZYcvfBCjP3gRmER/9MK8k15o0MJQntcNMYIx3tTXKiUXkfXnkIxDEC@DkQxBSP3leuH7hi5YFtF9//MEBu2l6UhI6V573mg45bI9N0XV5cTT4LjKTR0YXjdrsFuM0Pw@vRSVKq9phvdtlxb1UicIWQI@yaIi33WRUnxDGM8jewG3pdKywW0xZBzZbtbKcatklRPHTWF25QD2jA1tY0bShHFqwRg/1Vgp2E1nFwl226/KMmYg2CXYsv7f9aBSju5TyN4g3G1BIgYMFNpZg0dSaBvDOoQDihjEMXyicAOMrVZw@FV5KY/t5JenyTd/)

Comment: Fails on (250,177,'b') => b5 instead of b4

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>154 135</s>  139 bytes

```hs
f a b c|d<-[y|(x,y)<-zip"abcABC"$cycle[1189.4,1414.4,1297],x==c]!!0=c:(show$sum[1|x<-[0..10],max a b<d*2**(-x/2)&&(d/min a b)**2/2>2**x]-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/RboMwDPyVtKpKQAbiLC0wwaR2z/sClIcQWhUNGBqbFlD/nSV00vxg3/mk8/mmxvdL2y7LlShSEX2v87Cc7tTA5Ofh3AxbVenT@XW705NuLyVimkUCUKBwg2eJBFMUWm42rNDPdLx9/OzG767Eu7FOLIqQSeiUcfZ5HfAgoKGJub/f0zrumt7t/SDgMX@xmpEh@kunmr7o1PBGhs@m/yLllRgykXmNBbMNVlKOKdjr4CnPB4qA4GmHMluwtgdPBBw4eCeHnxCEAO/sMD8CImN/insLSCoQyMOQHxhgYu2rf3ZcmZTLLw)

- Saved 21 bytes thanks to @ovs !
- Fixed bug notified by @HyperNeutrino
  Added 0.2 to the precomputed constants `1189.2071150027211, 1414.213562373095, 1296.8395546510096` to fix rounding issues.
  The resulting table [here](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn//39uYmaebUFRZl6JgkpuYoFGTIquXbRGWk5@fpFKipaRlpaGboW@kaYOiohGhbahJlBUs6bCRjfaQE/P0CA2VjPa0NDCUs9Ex9DE0AREGVmax/4HAA) .

```
f a b c=    - function tacking sizes(a,b) and format (c).
|d<-[y|(x,y)<-zip"abcABC"$cycle[1189.4,1414.4,1297],x==c]!!0
            - get the precomputed constant relative to input(c)
c:(show$    - returns a string composed of format followed by result 
sum[...]-1  - count all valid sizes => 0 index
[1|x<-[0..10],max a b<d*2**(-x/2)&&(d/min a b)**2/2>2**x]
            - compute 0..10 sized and yield 1 if valid
```

- outputs "{format}-1" for invalid input.

Comment: You use `r` and `t` only once, that `let` is not necessary. And not defining `e` is 2 bytes shorter: https://tio.run/##TY7BbsIwEER/xSCE7XRDvcYtpEoO0HO/wPLBGBBR4xCRVnWi/HvqpJfuYfV2R5qZm20/L1U1jldiyYm44ZynuhtYgI7naV82S3tyh@P7cuU6V1004j4DVKgAZbYzEIrCmcVCFO6Ntbf7z6r99hqHEF3EZoPCgLdhss7PiUwSloZnyddrX9b/nyw8IY@CSZGP3pZ14W3zQZpHWX8RfSWBdKSfS0Efa2kmcQ8xH6ilHBgCAnUTZXFgXn/3TsGLBHqYeIugFNDjxPIVEIWYFWPGXw

Comment: And rewritting the last condition to `(d/min a b)**2/2>2**x` saves another 2 bytes

Comment: This fails on `1189, 841, 'a'`.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>41</s> 40 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ƵàS8/o¤11Ýmδ/₄*εü2í}5z+ï²Ç`8%èε¹{‹O_}O<«
```

Pair with the dimensions of the picture as as first input; letter as second input.
Outputs in the same case as the input, and with `-1` for error-cases above paper size `0`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AVAAr/9vc2FiaWX//8a1w6BTOC9vwqQxMcOdbc60L@KChCrOtcO8MsOtfTV6K8OvwrLDh2A4JcOozrXCuXvigLlPX31PPMKr//9bODQxLDU5NF0KQQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVCaFjE/2NbDy8IttDPP7TE0PDw3NxzW/QfNbVondt6eI/R4bW1plXah9dHHG5PsFA9vOLc1sjqRw07/eNr/W0Orf6v8z86OtrI0ELHyNI8VkcpUSlWRyE62lDHEMhJhnAsgUAHRCCEzE10TI2AXEcI19hQx8QEyHWCcI3MdAwNDQwQ8hYmhjqmliYQgVgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ƶà       # Push compressed integer 324
  S      # Convert it to a list of digits: [3,2,4]
   8/    # Divide each by 8: [3/8, 1/4, 1/2]
     o   # Take 2 to the power each of these: [1.296..., 1.189..., 1.414...]
¤        # Push the last item of the list (without popping the list itself):
         #  1.414... (which is sqrt(2))
 11Ý     # Push a list in the range [0,11]
    m    # Take sqrt(2) to the power each of these integers
     δ   # Apply double-vectorized over the two lists:
      /  #  Divide
₄*       # Multiply each by 1000
  ε      # Map each list of lists to:
   ü2    #  Create overlapping pairs of the list
     í   #  And then reverse each pair
  }5z+   # After the map: add 1/5 to each value (fix for A0 and C0)
      ï  # Floor every decimal by casting it to an integer
```

We now have a list of paper sizes, grouped per letter:

```python
[[[917,1297],[648,917],[458,648],[324,458],[229,324],[162,229],[114,162],[81,114],[57,81],[40,57],[28,40]],
 [[841,1189],[594,841],[420,594],[297,420],[210,297],[148,210],[105,148],[74,105],[52,74],[37,52],[26,37]],
 [[1000,1414],[707,1000],[500,707],[353,500],[250,353],[176,250],[125,176],[88,125],[62,88],[44,62],[31,44]]]
```

```python
²        # Push the second input-letter
 Ç       # Convert it to a list of codepoint integers
  `      # Pop that list, and push its only integer to the stack
   8%    # Take modulo-8 on it (A→1, B→2, C→3, a→1, b→2, c→3)
     è   # Index it into the list of lists (0-based modulair, so 3 will index into the
         # first inner list)
ε        # Map each pair in the list to:
 ¹       #  Push the first input-pair
  {      #  Sort this pair from lowest to highest
   ‹     #  Check if the sorted input-pair is higher than the current pair
    O    #  Sum those checks together
     _   #  And check that it's 0 (thus both were falsey)
}O       # After the map: get the amount of truthy values by summing
  <      # Decrease this by 1
   «     # And append it to the (implicit) second input-letter
         # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ƶà` is `324`.